# Click events running twice after re-opening the bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Currently working on Codeigniter apps

I am loading a view in bootstrap modal using ajax, the loaded view has some jquery events which further have ajax calls. The problem which I am getting is that when I click on button(which will execute ajax) it triggers only once but after closing the modal and reopening it that previously clicked event now running twice.

```
$(document).on('click','.open_form',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var task = $(this).attr('id');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo site_url();?>client/getModalView",
    data: {view:'invoice','<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?   >':'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>','task':task},
    cache: false,
    context: document.body,
    beforeSend:function(){
       if(task == 'expense')
       {
           $('.modal-title').html('Add Expense');
       }else if(task == 'uploadexpense'){
           $('.modal-title').html('Upload Expense');
       }else if(task == 'newDividend'){
           $('.modal-title').html('Add new Dividend Voucher');
       }else if(task == 'banks'){
           $('.modal-title').html('Upload bank Statement');
       }else{
           $('.modal-title').html('Add Invoice');
       }
       $('.modal-body').html('<img src="<?php echo site_url();?>assets/images/loading.gif"/>');
    },
    error:function(msg){
    },
    success:function(msg){
        msg = JSON.parse(msg);
        var html = '';
        $('#script').html(msg['script']);
        if(msg['file'] != '')
        {
            html = msg['file'];
        }

        html += msg['html'];
       $('.modal-body').html(html);
    }
}); 
return false;
```

});

Comment: are you posting any form here??

Comment: no but the view has form in itself

Comment: which particular event you are talking about!!

Comment: on('click',change etc) are triggering twice as the have ajax call in both